# Can't enter proxy credentials in Apple iTunes; all apps deleted

Tags: proxy, itunes, ipod

I have been using iTunes to automatically sync apps on my iPod Touch 5th gen.

My computer is behind a proxy which I have no access to directly, but I have credentials. So I can't get anyone to allow iTunes through, unfortunately. But none of this really matters because iTunes would automatically ask me for my credentials for the proxy and I could connect to the Apple servers with no problem.

For some reason, iTunes used to ask me to authorize my computer all the time. I would just log in and authorize it while the sync was occurring. Yesterday, I wasn't asked for proxy authentication creds and when it asked me to authorize my computer, I couldn't because iTunes couldn't communicate with the Apple servers.

This resulted in all my apps being deleted. I want to restore them, but now I don't know how.

The iTunes version I have is 11.0.4 on Windows 7 64bit. I recently upgraded from the previous version so I believe this version introduced the bug.

My exact question is: Does anyone know how to manually enter the proxy credentials into iTunes 11.0.4? If not, does anyone know how to restore my apps to my iPod from a previous backup without the use of an internet connection?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Well, really a workaround. Seems my proxy was blocking connections to iTunes. I worked around this by using Fiddler2 (network software) which reroutes the web proxy through itself, then out to the world.

So whatever problem iTunes was running into, it didn't have a problem going through localhost then out to the world. Good for my purposes at least.